# How to setup network subnet mask with systemd-networkd?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

The `systemd`'s `systemd-networkd` service enables to setup a networks using the `.network` unit files. However, as far as it is documented in the official man page (`man systemd.network`) it allows to configure a static IP address, but it does not specify how to set the subnet mask. How can do that using the `systemd` mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it:

in the `[Network]` section, where you configure the IP address (`Address=`) you can add the subnet mask by adding a `/` to it, and the subnet mask bit count afterwards. For instance, to configure the IP adress `1.2.3.4` with subnet mask `255.255.255.0` you would put it as following:

```
[Network]
Address=1.2.3.4/24
.
.
.
```